# Wit.ai Facebook Messenger Chatbot not receving or receivng messages lately using Python

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, wit-ai

I'm using the Python example provided here: https://github.com/wit-ai/pywit/blob/master/examples/messenger.py . I was receiving messages, however lately, a few days ago, but now it doesn't receive messages at all. However, when I try the Nodejs example: https://github.com/wit-ai/node-wit/blob/master/examples/messenger.js that receives messages instantly. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Facebook turns off your webhook, if your app fails to respond quickly enough for a while. Try removing it from your app settings, set it up again, and see if that changes things.

Answer (score 0):

Though wit.ai is totally free, but seems like there is rate limiting.
May be your app crossed rate limit, and then it stopped responding?
Read more about it here https://wit.ai/faq

Comment: If that is the case then I should stop receiving messages with Nodejs, the moment I switch to Nodejs, I start receiving messages instantly.

Comment: I've contacted with wit.ai, they said they are not that strict about api rate limiting. So, I think there could be other issues. You could try unsubscribe, then subscribe again when this occures. 
Facebook stops sending new requests after 20 minutes of webhook inactivity.

Comment: Thanks Azizul Hakim, I think the problem is related asynchronicity due to which the code with Nodejs works correctly and Python has some latency.